# How to change python version (interactive mode) in macports?

Tags: python, macos

```
[mac-120183:/opt/local/bin] name% sudo port select --set python python33
Selecting 'python33' for 'python' succeeded. 'python33' is now active.
[mac-120183:/opt/local/bin] name% python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[mac-120183:/opt/local/bin] name% which python
/usr/bin/python
[mac-120183:/opt/local/bin] name% which python3.3
/opt/local/bin/python3.3
```

How may I switch my python to python3.3 when I type python to use interactive mode in command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter you get when you type `python` is included in OS X, which means programs written for OS X will expect `python` to be Python 2.7. Changing that is dangerous because it could break programs, and that's probably why macports isn't messing with it.

If you really want to, you can do it by putting Macports' `bin` directory before `/usr/bin` in your [`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29):

```
export PATH=/path/to/macports/bin:$PATH
```

You should be able to find the correct path with `which python33`.

You could also overwrite `/usr/bin/python` with a link to Python 3.3, but that's incredibly dangerous, and I don't recommend it.